# Can `android.os.Handler.postDelayed` fail?

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I would like to run a function periodically every 5 seconds in a foreground service. I use `android.os.Handler.postDelayed` for that, like this:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Do some work

        scheduleTask();
    }
};

private void scheduleTask() {
    handler.postDelayed(updater, 5000);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    scheduleTask();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
}
```

Is it possible for the `handler.postDelayed` to fail? Can the OS just cancel the delayed request? How to catch that?
I need this to run stable for days.

Comment: there ll be possible case : check at the service destroy method..

Comment: Well `Handler` attached to Looper in turns the Thread and in your case Main thread. So if the process destroy then `Handler` will destroy i think. Other than that i don't think OS will cancel delayed calls individually.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is in the foreground then there is no chance that the handler gets cancelled. It only gets cancelled when the app is running in background for some time or the Main thread has been destroyed.

For reference you can read the android developers documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler

Comment: The app is in the background, but I run this code in a foreground service